# Row count result from SELECT COUNT() not matching rows returned by SELECT id

Tags: soql, count

Fairly new to SFDC and primarily using it as a source for our data warehouse.

We're ingesting data using the Bulk API and are manually checking rowcounts through workbench.

Running into an odd issue on Workbench where `SELECT COUNT() FROM recordtype` returns a count of 31 but `SELECT id FROM recordtype` returns 20 rows. Surprisingly `SELECT id FROM recordtype GROUP BY id` returned 31 rows.

Our admin is saying that 11 rows are marked as Reserved/Not usable.

If that's the case, shouldn't `COUNT()` also exclude them and return 20 as the count? Flummoxed by why the group by id returned 31 rows. Feels like this is a bug. How does Workbench query SFDC? Does it use the standard SOAP APIs or some other mechanism? Is the issue with the API?